# Is it safe to call react hooks based on a constant condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, react-hooks

The [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) require that the same hooks and in the same order are called on every render. And there is an explanation about what goes wrong if you break this rule. For example this code:

```
function App() {
  console.log('render');
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(true);
  const [first] = useState('first');
  console.log('first is', first);
  if (flag) {
    const [second] = useState('second');
    console.log('second is', second);
  }
  const [third] = useState('third');
  console.log('third is', third);

  useEffect(() => setFlag(false), []);

  return null;
}
```

Outputs to console

```
render 
first is first 
second is second 
third is third 
render 
first is first 
third is second
```

And causes a warning or an error.

But what about conditions that do not change during the element lifecycle?

```
const DEBUG = true;

function TestConst() {
  if (DEBUG) {
    useEffect(() => console.log('rendered'));
  }

  return <span>test</span>;
}
```

This code doesn't really break the rules and seems to work fine. But it still triggers the eslint warning.

Moreover it seems to be possible to write similar code based on props:

```
function TestState({id, debug}) {
  const [isDebug] = useState(debug);

  if (isDebug) {
    useEffect(() => console.log('rendered', id));
  }

  return <span>{id}</span>;
}

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => setCounter(1), []);
  return (
    <div>
      <TestState id="1" debug={false}/>
      <TestState id="2" debug={true}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This code works as intended.

So is it safe to call hooks inside a condition when I am sure that it is not going to change? Is it possible to modify the eslint rule to recognise such situations?

The question is more about the real requirement and not the way to implement similar behaviour. As far as I understand it is important to

> ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component
>   renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of
>   Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls

And there is a place for exceptions to this rule: "Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you can write hooks conditionally like you mentioned above and it may work currently, it can lead to unexpected behavior in the future. For instance in the current case you aren't modifying the `isDebug` state.

Demo

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
function TestState({id, debug}) {
  const [isDebug, setDebug] = useState(debug);

  if (isDebug) {
    useEffect(() => console.log('rendered', id));
  }
  
  const toggleButton = () => {
    setDebug(prev => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{id}</span>
       <button type="button" onClick={toggleButton}>Toggle debug</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => setCounter(1), []);
  return (
    <div>
      <TestState id="1" debug={false}/>
      <TestState id="2" debug={true}/>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

As a rule of thumb you shouldn't violate the rules since it may cause problems in future. You could handle the above scenarios in the following way without violating the rules

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
function TestState({id, debug}) {
  const [isDebug, setDebug] = useState(debug);

    useEffect(() => {
      if(isDebug) {
        console.log('rendered', id)
      }
    }, [isDebug]);
  
  const toggleButton = () => {
    setDebug(prev => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{id}</span>
       <button type="button" onClick={toggleButton}>Toggle debug</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => setCounter(1), []);
  return (
    <div>
      <TestState id="1" debug={false}/>
      <TestState id="2" debug={true}/>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand that `TestState` relies on the current 'per element' requirement and might break if some internal react changes turn it into 'per component' requirement. But I can't imagine how `const DEBUG` might break in the future. Also `const [isDebug] = useState(debug);` is written this way to ensure that it doesn't change.

Comment: @UjinT34, at present you are not modifying the isDebug state, but someone in future may just add a setter function and provide a method to modify isDebug state. This may break the app.

Comment: A problem is that this approach leads to *a lot of* boilerplate code once the hook you want to use conditionally is for example a custom hook that contains a multitude of use* calls.

Answer (score 5):

For your use-case I don't see the problem, I don't see how this can break in the future, and you are right that it works as intended.

However, I think the warning is actually legit and should be there at all times, because this can be a potential bug in your code (not in this particular one)

So what I'd do in your case, is to disable `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` rule for that line.

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 3):

This hook rule address common cases when problems that may occur with conditional hook calls:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.

If a developer isn't fully aware of consequences, this rule is a safe choice and can be used as a rule of thumb.

But the actual rule here is:

> ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders

It's perfectly fine to use loops, conditions and nested functions, as long as it's guaranteed that hooks are called in *the same quantity and order within the same component instance*.

Even `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'` condition can change during component lifespan if `process.env.NODE_ENV` property is reassigned at runtime.

If a condition is constant, it can be defined outside a component to guarantee that:

```
const isDebug = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

function TestConst() {
  if (isDebug) {
    useEffect(...);
  }
  ...
}
```

In case a condition derives from dynamic value (notably initial prop value), it can be memoized:

```
function TestConst({ debug }) {
  const isDebug = useMemo(() => debug, []);

  if (isDebug) {
    useEffect(...);
  }
  ...
}
```

Or, since [`useMemo` isn't guaranteed to preserve values](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) in future React releases, `useState` (as the question shows) or `useRef` can be used; the latter has no extra overhead and a suitable semantics:

```
function TestConst({ debug }) {
  const isDebug = useRef(debug).current;

  if (isDebug) {
    useEffect(...);
  }
  ...
}
```

In case there's `react-hooks/rules-of-hooks` ESLint rule, it can be disabled per line basis.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't use this pattern. It may work in your example but it is not nice (or idiomatic).

The standard pattern (for good reason) is that initial state is declared in the constructor and then updated in response to some condition in the body (setState). React Hooks mirror this functionality in stateless components - so it should work the same.

Secondly, I cannot see how it is useful to dynamically add this piece of state and potentially cause rendering problems later down the line. In your example, a simple const would work just as well - there is no reason to use dynamic state.

Consider this:

```
return (<React.Fragment>{second}</React.Fragment>)
```

This breaks with a Reference error whenever you don't have `second` defined.